# Do I need a return ticket to Canada if I'm a Japanese National?

Tags: usa, transit, canada, japan, one-way

Here's my situation:

**Passengers**

- Canadian National (Me)
- Japanese National (My wife), also Permanent Resident of Canada

**Itinerary**

- YUL->MSP
- MSP->HND

We are going to Japan with One-way tickets.
I contact Delta (the airline for the trip) through Twitter and they tell me I don't need a return ticket but my wife does.
Confused, I contact Delta on the phone explaining the situation.

The lady on the phone tells me: 
-*Sorry the guy on Twitter is wrong, you (Canadian National) need to get a return ticket or any ticket out of Japan but your wife (Japanese National) doesn't need one.*

Relieved, I write back to the guy on twitter and tell him he's wrong.
He replies to me with this:

> National Japan (JP)             /Residence Canada (CA) Embarkation
>   Canada (CA)         /Transit USA (US) Destination Japan (JP)
>
> (SEE NOTE 60190) 
>       **NOTE 60190: Passengers must have a return/onward ticket**.

I'm back to Square #1....

**Since Delta can't answer my question, here's my question: Do I need a return ticket? Does my wife needs one?**

Thank you

Comment: Are you flying or transiting through the USA?

Comment: We are transiting through the USA (MSP)

Comment: OP,  you missed a great opportunity to call yourself Gaijim :-)

Comment: @John this was too good for not doing it. Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The guy on Twitter has misread Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger documents.

The NOTE 60190 appears in the USA transit section, and means that she needs an onward ticket departing the USA.

> Visa required, except for Nationals of Japan with a biometric
>   passport (with an electronic chip symbol on the cover) and an
>   Electronic System for Travel Authorization (ESTA) in transit.
>   (SEE NOTE 60190)
>
> NOTE 60190: Passengers must have a return/onward ticket.
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> - There are no transit facilities, passengers must comply with
>     all entry regulations for the USA.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael! That makes a lot of sense!

Comment: You can tell him I said so, too :)

Comment: would you know if I will need a ticket out of Japan?

Comment: @GaijinJim For a Canada citizen entering Japan, Timatic says: "- Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry." This means the airline may deny boarding if you haven't got a ticket out of Japan. They aren't guaranteed to deny boarding, and you aren't guaranteed to be refused entry without a return/onward ticket, but they often will.

Comment: Once again, very much appreciated Michael!

Comment: @GaijinJim Aeroflot will give you an e-ticket number without paying supposedly valid until 24 hours after issuing. Some people claim this works. If not you can check out budget airlines like Airasia and buy a one way ticket to China, South Korea or The Philippines.